# How to connect to hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Hi I have a question actually in big data platform. We can connect to hive through beeline(beeline commands) in putty or odbc connection with any GUI Sql tools. But how can we connect to Hbase? As per my understanding we have Hbase in Shell format or in Java API format. But how do we connect to Hbase?

Answer (score 1):

You can start the HBase interactive shell using “hbase shell” command as shown below. first you need to go to hadoop cluster (by ssh or putty etc... based on your environment) where hbase is installed and execute below.

`hbase shell`

[image]

- [Apache HBase Browser App added in Hue 2.5 if you are using cloudera.](https://vimeo.com/72357888)
- You can also use Apache Pheonix to connect to hbase to do  operations programatically Use JDBC to get a connection to an HBase cluster like this:

  [`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:server1,server2:3333",props);` see the phoenix docs..](https://phoenix.apache.org/)
- other tools which are not so popular are 
  1.hbaseexplorer
  2.Toad for Cloud Databases
  3.HareDB HBase Client
  4.hrider

Comment: ’s. I mean at initial stage. When we are in putty. We are in HDFS environment.So, from there how do we go? Like: To connect to hive,we go through beeline commands in HDFS abs get connected to hive. two bullet points mentioning apps are using HBase with GUI mode?

Comment: ssh –i username@hostipaddress were you able to do ? if so then execute hbase shell see this https://mapr.com/products/mapr-sandbox-hadoop/tutorials/tutorial-getting-started-with-hbase-shell/ for example....

Comment: Thank You. I will follow the link you shared.

Comment: There is also an Apache Phoenix driver that puts SQL interface over HBase.